# Error Installing Python MySQLdb on Windows 7

Tags: python, windows-7, mysql-python, activestate

Please see the following stacktrace, is this a permissions issue?

```
C:\Project\MySQL-python-1.2.3>python setup.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 15, in <module>
    metadata, options = get_config()
  File "C:\Project\MySQL-python-1.2.3\setup_windows.py", line 7, in get_config
    serverKey = _winreg.OpenKey(_winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, options['registry_key'])
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified

C:\Project\MySQL-python-1.2.3>
```

Python version is (ActiveState) 2.7.1

Comment: Did you installed MySQL first?

Comment: @Fabio Diniz - i do not have the MySQL server installed b/c I will be connecting to a remote host.

Comment: MySQL is a prerequisite, as said in the README of MySQLDb

Comment: @Fabio Diniz - right you are sir.  Please provide as an answer below and I will accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL is a prerequisite, as said in the README of MySQLDb

Answer (score 1):

Same issue here, with same version of Python and MySQL installed (as part of XAMPP). Presumably the pre-requisite is for the "vanilla" MySQL installation and not one included in an *AMP package.

It's not an answer to the problem of installing from the tarball, but binary packages of MySQLdb compatible with ActiveState Python 2.7.1 and Windows 7 are available at this site:-

http://servut.us/akx/2010/09/mysqldb-windows-binaries-python-26-27/

Answer (score 0):

Edit the following line in the site.cfg file, part of the mysql-python build directory, to point to your MySQL location.

```
registry_key = SOFTWARE\MySQL AB\MySQL Server 5.0
```